# JavaScript interface works but need to call the function twice

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I try to set the `statusBarColor` of my Android app by pressing a button in my web application. I got this working but the application will only display a blue status bar when I press the blue button twice. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://myurl.com");


    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
    }

}
```

--

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setStatusBarColor(String color) {
        ((MainActivity)mContext).setColor(color);
    }

}
```

--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="White" onClick="setStatusBarColor('#ffffff');" />
    <input type="button" value="Blue" onClick="setStatusBarColor('#0073cf')" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setStatusBarColor(color) {
            Android.setStatusBarColor(color);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

--

Any help will be much appreciated. I am out of options here :-(

---

**UPDATE:**

Upon debugging a little deeper I get:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Does the functionality of the "white" button work as expected?

Comment: Nope... also the white button needs to be pressed twice...

Comment: Add a `console.log(1)` or `alert(1)` to the `setStatusBarColor()` function... does that message get displayed on both button presses or only the 2nd?

Comment: Both.... I think it is in the android part... I am debugging a little deeper and get:        android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this working... I needed to add "runOnUiThread" around my setStatusBarColor android function. So my setColor function needs to be:

```
   public void setColor(final String color){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this solves your problem. `JavascriptInterface` annotated methods are called in a `JavaBridge` background thread. That's why you need the context switch.